# How to display list elements inside a loop one by one?

Tags: python

I have a list containing:

```py
list1= [ 'Math' ,  'Science ', 'English' ]
```

And I tried this code to display the lines in list 1 as titles

```py
for text_files in list1:
    i=0
    while i < len(list1):
        print(list1[i])
        i+=1
        print (" Passed" )
```

my output is supposed to be:

```
Math
Passed
Science
Passed
English
Passed
```

But the output I'm having is being repeated multiple times.

Comment: Of course it is. You iterate `n*n` times: first is outer for loop and second - inner `while`. Just get rid of `while` like `for f in list1: print(f'{f}\nPassed')` (also note that you can just `print('\nPassed\n'.join(list1))`)

Comment: @SUTerliakov `'\nPassed\n'.join(list1)` will miss Passed for last item

Comment: You can use this style: `print("\n".join([f"{item}\nPassed" for item in list1]))`. `"\n".join()` = join list of string by adding "\n" between two items. `f"{item} something"` = create text with format. `[... for item in list1]` = create new list from list1 with modifier at `...`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has indentation issues among other things, for iterating (looping) over a list you can simply do `for item in list`. If you want to print two things with a space between them, you can do `print(item1,item2)`

So if you combine the two you get

```
#loop over each item
for subject in list1:
    # Notice there's no space in passed
    print(subject, "Passed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use either for-statement or while-statement

```
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    print("{}\nPassed".format(list1[i]))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
    while i < len(list1):
        print(list1[i])
        i+=1
        print (" Passed" )
```

Is basically doing the same thing as a for-loop. So you're doing a for-loop inside a for-loop.

Based on your comment, you should do

```
for text_files in list1:
    for file in text_files:
        print(file)
        print("Passed")
```

You can also do

```
print("/n".join("/n".join(
            file+"/nPassed" for file in text_files
        ) 
        for text_files in list1)
    )
```

Comment: on my code its only an example ,  there is a separate list that is inside the while loop , how can i go over that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically using 2 loops, that's why you are getting the output multiple times.
One loop is enough. And you have already written it.

```py
list1 = ['Math' , 'Science ', 'English']
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    print(list1[i])
    i+=1
    print("Passed")
```

**Output**

```
Math
Passed
Science 
Passed
English
Passed
```

Or you can use `for-loop` see the sample code

```py
list1 = ['Math' , 'Science ', 'English']
for text in list1:
    print(text)
    print("Passed")
```

**Output**

```
Math
Passed
Science 
Passed
English
Passed
```